# encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error when using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, encoding, python-multithreading

I'm using threading to increase my code speed. This is my main code:

```
t1 = Thread(target=process_multiple_pages, args=(splited_page_number_list[0]))
t2 = Thread(target=process_multiple_pages, args=(splited_page_number_list[1]))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

`splited_page_number_list` is a list with 2 list in it:
`[[1, 2, 3, 4, .... 57], [58, 59, 60, 61, .... 114]]`

`process_multiple_pages()` processes all page numbers in list:

```
def process_multiple_pages(page_number_list):
    for i in page_number_list:
        process_page(i)
```

`process_page()` gets page for passed page number and processes it.

```
def process_page(page_number, subcategory_url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.yes24.com/24/Category/Display/001001046013001?FetchSize=40&PageNumber={}".format(str(page_number))).text, "lxml")
```

When I run my code, it works but warning `encoding error : input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0xEB 0x85 0x84 0x20` appears every time processing new page. Sometimes `I/O error : encoder error` appears too.

When I run this code without multithreading and with only one `page_number_list`, the warning doesn't appear. Why is this happening? And is it okay to ignore it?

Comment: `args=` needs `tuple` and this needs `,` inside `()` - `args=( splited_page_number_list[0], )`. Without `,` it skips `()` and you have `args=splited_page_number_list[0]` and it runs funtions with many separated values as `process_multiple_pages( 1, 2, 3, 4, .... 57 )` instead of running with list `process_multiple_pages( [1, 2, 3, 4, .... 57] )`

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you define `def process_page(page_number, subcategory_url):` - so it expect two values - but later you run `process_page(i)` with single value and this should generate error.

Comment: when you use `.format()` then you don't have to use `str()` - you can do `"...{}".format(page_number)`

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing. You could check what you have in `page_number_list` and you could assing url to variable to display it and later use it in `requests.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't run your code but I see some mistakes.

The main mistakes is: `args=` needs `tuple` with arguments but `()` DOESN'T create tuple. To create tuple you need `,`.

```
args = splited_page_number_list[0],  # <-- `,` at the end to create tuple
```

but when you create tuple in `Thread` then you have to use `()` to show that this `,` is for creating `tuple` and not to separate other arguments in `Thread()`

```
args = ( splited_page_number_list[0], )
```

---

```
t1 = Thread(target=process_multiple_pages, args=(splited_page_number_list[0],) )  # `,`
t2 = Thread(target=process_multiple_pages, args=(splited_page_number_list[1],) )  # `,`
```

---

Another mistake (which should generate error)

You define function with two arguments

```
def process_page(page_number, subcategory_url):
```

but later you run it with single value

```
process_page(i)
```

and this should generate error.

---

Frankly, I would use `ThreadPool` instead of two threads - you could send all numbers as one list (without spliting) and set two threads in `Pool` and it will run all using only two thread.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

# --- functions ---

def process_page(page_number):
    url = "http://www.yes24.com/24/Category/Display/001001046013001?FetchSize=40&PageNumber={}".format(page_number)
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(f'{response.status_code} | {url}')
    
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    #... rest ...

    return f"some result from page {page_number}"

# --- main ---

page_numbers = range(1, 11)

with ThreadPool(2) as p:
    results = p.map(process_page, page_numbers)
    
    for item in results:
        print(item)
```

Result

```
200 | http://www.yes24.com/24/Category/Display/001001046013001?FetchSize=40&PageNumber=3
200 | http://www.yes24.com/24/Category/Display/001001046013001?FetchSize=40&PageNumber=1
200 | http://www.yes24.com/24/Category/Display/001001046013001?FetchSize=40&PageNumber=2
200 | http://www.yes24.com/24/Category/Display/001001046013001?FetchSize=40&PageNumber=4
200 | http://www.yes24.com/24/Category/Display/001001046013001?FetchSize=40&PageNumber=5
200 | http://www.yes24.com/24/Category/Display/001001046013001?FetchSize=40&PageNumber=7
200 | http://www.yes24.com/24/Category/Display/001001046013001?FetchSize=40&PageNumber=8
200 | http://www.yes24.com/24/Category/Display/001001046013001?FetchSize=40&PageNumber=6
200 | http://www.yes24.com/24/Category/Display/001001046013001?FetchSize=40&PageNumber=9
200 | http://www.yes24.com/24/Category/Display/001001046013001?FetchSize=40&PageNumber=10
some result from page 1
some result from page 2
some result from page 3
some result from page 4
some result from page 5
some result from page 6
some result from page 7
some result from page 8
some result from page 9
some result from page 10
```